# How get i get an AddedPicture center on a page word

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, shapes

To get around the fact that the manual way to insert a pdf in a word don't give really good quality result.
I'm trying to insert pictures that have been nicely converted from a pdf to png with Imagemagick in a word with a macro.

The moment where i struggle is when i want the picture to get in a middle of each page and don't overlap each over.
I come up with this but i don't understand why it seems that `AllowOverlap` and `wdShapeCenter` do nothing while `wdWrapTopBottom` work properly. The picture get stuck to the top-left corner'

```
Sub Test()
Dim objShape As Shape
    strPath = "Some.png"
    'insert the image
    Set objShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture( _
        FileName:=strPath, LinkToFile:=False, _
        SaveWithDocument:=True)
    objShape.WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = False
    objShape.Top = WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter
    objShape.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTopBottom
End Sub
```

I tried to use `Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture` to resolve the overlap problem but i can't get the picture move from the top-left corner neither.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Shp As Shape
With Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture)
  .Display
  If .Name <> "" Then
    Set Shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=.Name, _
      LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Anchor:=Selection.Range)
    With Shp
      .LockAspectRatio = True
      .Height = InchesToPoints(2)
      .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
      .Left = wdShapeCenter
      .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
      .Top = wdShapeCenter
      .WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = False
    End With
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

With the above code, the inserted pic will be positioned in the center of the page. If there's already one centered there, the existing pic will be pushed down.

In light of your additional information, you should use something like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim iShp As InlineShape, sWdth As Single, sHght As Single
With Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture)
  .Display
  If .Name <> "" Then
    Set Shp = .InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=.Name, _
      LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=Selection.Range)
      With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
        sWdth = .PageWidth - .LeftMargin - .RightMargin
        sHght = .PageHeight - .TopMargin - .LeftMargin
      End With
    With iShp
      .LockAspectRatio = True
      .Width = sWdth
      If .Height > sHght Then .Height = sHght
    End With
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks macropod, It's work nicely but through my tests it's push other picture beside **only if they are small enough and not to a new page**. To come around this trouble I added some Jump page `Selection.InsertAfter ChrW(12)`, so each picture got is own page

Comment: Your post didn't say anything about your pictures being put on separate pages, in which case you probably should not be using Shapes - you should probably be using InlineShapes - and sizing each pic to fit the page!!

Answer (score 0):

Finaly with your help I come up with this.
It center and place on it's own page pictures from a Folder.

```
Sub Folder_Picture_To_Word()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim intResult As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFolderPath As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

'the dialog is displayed to the user
intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
'checks if user has cancled the dialog
If intResult <> 0 Then
    'dispaly message box
    strFolderPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker _
        ).SelectedItems(1)
    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        'get file path
        strPath = objFile.Path
        Selection.InsertAfter ChrW(12)
        'insert the image
        Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strPath, _
            LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Anchor:=Selection.Range)
        With shp
          '.LockAspectRatio = True
          '.Height = InchesToPoints(8)
          .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
          .Left = wdShapeCenter
          .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
          .Top = wdShapeCenter
          .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTopBottom
          .WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = False
        End With
        'Go to next Page to get ready for a new picture
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext
    Next objFile
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToPrevious  'Go to second last page
    'To delete the extra jump page made in the loop
    Selection.Delete
End If
End Sub
```